# Ansible: How to ping from one Remote Node to another?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am using Ansible in Linux.

I have 3 servers:

```
A: a.domain.com
B: b.domain.com
C: c.domain.com
```

I am running an `ansible-playbook` command, in server `A`, but I want to make a ping from server `B` to server C, the equivalent to:

```bash
ping -c 4 c.domain.com # from inside server B
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: "_The equivalent to `ping`_" do you really like to make a connection test on OSI Layer 3 with Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP) only? Or are other layers like 4 and protocols like UDP/TCP more interesting? In general I understand that you like to know "How to connect from Control Node (A) to Remote Node (B) and execute or connect from there to Remote Node (C)?", right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thats what I want :)

Answer (score 1):

Since your requirement is ICMP ping which differs highly from [`ping` module – Try to connect to host, verify a usable python and return pong on success](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/ping_module.html), you also not want to use the [`wait_for` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_module.html) to test the network connection, using a [Custom Module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html) for [`icmp_ping.py`](https://gist.github.com/ageis/face10be67b26e4519662e19290e06ff) and with resolved dependencies

```bash
pip install netifaces
...
Collecting netifaces
  Downloading https://repository.example.com/ ... (31 kB)
Installing collected packages: netifaces
Successfully installed netifaces-0.11.0
```

a minimal test playbook executed from Control Node (`a.example.com`) on Remote Node (`b.example.com`)

```yaml
---
- hosts: b.example.com
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: ICMP ping
    icmp_ping:
      dest: c.example.com
      count: 4
    register: result

  - name: Show result
    debug:
      msg: "{{ result }}"
```

will result for Remote Node (`c.example.com`) into an output of

```yaml
TASK [ICMP ping] ****************************************************************
ok: [b.example.com]

TASK [Show result] **************************************************************
ok: [b.example.com] =>
  msg:
    changed: false
    failed: false
    msg: |-
      PING c.example.com (192.168.2.4) from 192.168.2.3 : 56(84) bytes of data.
      64 bytes from c.example.com (192.168.2.4): icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.373 ms
      64 bytes from c.example.com (192.168.2.4): icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.540 ms
      64 bytes from c.example.com (192.168.2.4): icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.390 ms
      64 bytes from c.example.com (192.168.2.4): icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.629 ms

      --- c.example.com ping statistics ---
      4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3000ms
      rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.373/0.483/0.629/0.106 ms
    packet_loss: 0%
    packets_rx: 4
    packets_tx: 4
    rtt:
      avg: 0
      max: 0
      mdev: 0
      min: 0
```