# Ansible: 'block' and 'with_items'

Tags: loops, ansible, block

Is it OK / possible to use `block` in Ansible with `with_items`?

Say I have a list of servers. Before performing any task on these servers, the server is pinged.

- If the ping succeeds, perform a block of tasks
- If the ping fails, skip the block of tasks for this server and move on to the next server in the list

I've tried the following, expecting the when statements to be evaluated and then the block of tasks to be actioned.

```yaml
- name: Perform following tasks only when server Pings successfully
  block:
    - name: print something for the sake of having a task here
      debug: msg="here's a block of Tasks"

    - name: Print the dynamic inventory item
      debug:
        msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"

    - name: Apply the foo config template
      ansible.builtin.template:
        src: templates/src.j2
        dest: /etc/foo.conf

    - name: Pause for some random reason
      pause:
        seconds: 5
  when:
    - ping_result.rc == 0                              # CONTROL LOOP
    - item.fqdn == inventory_hostname
  with_items: "{{ my_dict }}"
```

The above threw an error,

```
'with_items' is not a valid attribute for a Block.
```

I was trying to keep the playbook neat by just applying the When statement to a single block of tasks, rather than having a when statement for each task.

Answer (score 2):

> *The above threw an error:  "`with_items` is not a valid attribute for a Block"*

Right, this is the expected behavior.

> *Is it OK / possible to use blocks in Ansible with `with_items` ?*

The short answer is no. According the documentation [Grouping tasks with blocks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#grouping-tasks-with-blocks)

> *All tasks in a block inherit directives applied at the block level. Most of what you can apply to a single task (with the exception of `loop`s) can be applied at the block level ...*

To achieve your goal

> *I was trying to keep the playbook neat by just applying the `when` statement to a single block of tasks, rather than having a when statement for each task*

you may read about

- [`include_tasks` module – Dynamically include a task list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/include_tasks_module.html)
- [`import_tasks` module – Import a task list](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/import_tasks_module.html)
- [What's the difference between `include_tasks` and `import_tasks`?](https://serverfault.com/a/875292/448950)

---

Additionally, regarding your use case description

> *Before performing any task on these servers, the server is pinged.*

I like to recommend to use the [`wait_for` module – Waits for a condition before continuing](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_module.html) instead. Please take also note of [Ansible: How to `icmp_ping` from one Remote Node to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75149464/6771046).